# Простая работа со строками, списками, словарями и файлами Python

Tags: python

Роберт играет в компьютерные игры. На протяжении N часов компьютер каждый час фиксирует информацию о том, играл ли Роберт в компьютер. Необходимо сказать в каком периоде K часов Роберт играл большего всего.

Пытался сравнивать два списка, но так и не добрался до решения задачи
`

```
import random
KeyList = ['1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00',
        '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '24:00']
time = {}       #словарь для записи в значение играл/не играл(0 - не играл, 1 - играл)
for i in KeyList:
  time[i] = random.randint(0, 1)


print(time)

#перенос значений в список, чтобы сравнить два списка
values = []   
for v in time.values():
    values.append(v)
print(KeyList)
print(values)

pam = []  #список для индексов едениц
count = len(values)
while count > 0:    #поиск индекса каждой еденицы
    for item in values:
        if values[item] == 1:
            print(values.index(item))
            pam.append(values.index(item))
            i = values.index(item)
            values[i] = 0
            count = count - 1
print(pam)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
KeyList = ['1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00',
           '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00',
           '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00',
           '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00',
           '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '24:00']
# словарь для записи в значение играл/не играл(0 - не играл, 1 - играл)
time = {}
for i in KeyList:
    time[i] = random.randint(0, 1)

print(time)

# перенос значений в список, чтобы сравнить два списка
values = []
for v in time.values():
    values.append(v)
print(KeyList)
print(values)

# собственно, решение задачи
count = 0
max_item = 0
for i in time.values():
    if i:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 0
    if count > max_item:
        max_item = count
print(max_item)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!